# LP on Mac prints WAYY too big

Tags: python, macos, terminal

#### The issue

when using the `ls` command on mac via python `os.system()`, the printed content is much too large.

AKA, the entire PDF file I am trying to print(visible [here](https://www.file.io/N9Sm/download/FE1xEsQrhNyw)) cannot be seen, and only the bottom half of the bottom left section of 9 can be seen.

#### What I have tried

I have not tried much, since I could not find many resources on this topic online, but, I have attempted to print it with Preview to determine if it was a problem with the actual PDF, and the result was flawless, so, I copied the scale from Preview into the `lp` command, to result in the final command:

`ls -o scaling=32 soduko.pdf`

**Any Help would be greatly appreciated!**

###### Note: Whatever I try will be printed in real life, and costs money and ink, therefore, the best solution would be the one without any brute force or several tries.

Comment: this seems relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/681845/printing-via-commandline-cups-with-photo-printer  also its not `ls`

Comment: @JoranBeasley I have tried the `-o fit-to-page` option, and now, it is printing at the correct size, however, it seems to have stopped printing halfway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `-o fit-to-page` argument has fixed my answer. Thank you for the help! The final command was:

`lp -o fit-to-page soduko.pdf`